# WebJobs upgrade to latest Nuget package. Upgrades app.config to not match WindwosAzure.Storage DLL version

Tags: nuget, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

On a v.04rc WebJobs subproject, after performing Nuget Package Update of the "Webjobs" package to v1.0.0-rc1 (note: v0.5 Azure SDK contains old version: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/06/announcing-the-0-5-0-beta-preview-of-microsoft-azure-webjobs-sdk/)

The project now reference v4.1.0.0 and app.config has:
bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />

But DLL that has been put in 'bin' is version 4.0.1.0.  Which is the minimum version dependency in Nuget.

Answer (score 1):

Learning: don't trust Nuget update in Visual Studio.

Update dependant packages FIRST yourself.

In this instance I updated in the following order, and now packages, bin and app.config all agree:

1. Newtonsoft.Json
2. Microsoft.Data.OData
3. WindowsAzure.Storage
4. WindowssAzure.WebJobs